# Intellisense not working in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, configuration, sql-server-2012

I have enabled the intellisense in SQL Server 2012 and refresh the local cache. But it's not working.Enable option: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> General -> IntelliSense.Please suggest your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution. I have downloaded Sql complete for Sql server 2012 and installed it. It was working now.